# Why AWS RDS service needs two subnets from different AZs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As part of our project we are using AWS RDS postgres service. While creating RDS service AWS mandated to create two subnets from different AZs (ex: us-west-2a and us-west-2b). But we have only one subnet. Is there any way to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is for being high availability and effect on your system design performance, if you check AWS design  best practices you will see how does it take part in performance and availability of you system

Comment: Did you select the High Availability (Multi-AZ) option when launching the database?

Comment: No, we selected single AZ option

Answer (score 0):

To ensure High Availability, you need to specify subnets in two different Availability Zones (AZs).

Each AZ operates in a different data center. If an AZ fails, the Amazon RDS service will automatically launch a replacement database in a different AZ. Therefore, it requires a minimum of two different AZs to be specfiied.

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between subnets and AZs and why two AZs need two subnets? Can both AZs share a subnet?

Comment: @PetrusTheron A **Region** contains multiple **Availability Zones** (AZs). Think of an AZ as a physical data center. A **VPC** is a logical network with no physical component. A VPC contains **subnets** and each subnet exists in a single AZ. So, traffic within a subnet is always sent within a single data center (not always true, but close enough) for high-speed communication. Thus, if you are using two different AZs, then you will need at least two different subnets. However, multiple subnets can exist in one AZ. So, VPC contains AZs that contain subnets that contain resources.

Comment: Thanks, @John Rotenstein.